# How to change the `mail from` attribute while using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send mail via html contact form.
The problem is, mail received by recipient shows the authentication mail id (mygmailid@gmail.com) I using. This is how it looks like more or less:

```
On Feb 11, 2017 4:49 PM, "Name" <mygmailid@gmail.com> wrote:
Full Name:  xyz
Subject:    Testing PHP Mail
Phone:  1234567890
Email:  xxxx@xxmail.com
Comments:   Testing mail
```

I would like to change it. Do you know it there is a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you need to add this two extra config in your phpmailer script.

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');
$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'Mailbox name');
```

And, that's it.
N.B. : you may also need to clear out previous replyTo config by putting this line at first

```
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
```

Comment: This is the correct way to set it in PHPMailer, however, gmail (which the OP is using) imposes some additional restrictions - you can't use arbitrary from addresses, though you can configure it to use preset aliases.